# How to display datetimepicker outside of scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a long table that needs to be displayed inside a small area so I'm using `overflow-x: scroll;` to make a **horizontal scrollbar** under the table.

Inside the table, I have a few input fields with `datetimepicker`.

My **problem** is when I `click` on the **input field** to show the `datatimepicker`, it makes a **vertical scrollbar** and displays inside these 2 scrollbars.

```js
jQuery('#birthday1').datetimepicker({
  format: "DD/MM/YYYY"
});
jQuery('#birthday2').datetimepicker({
  format: "DD/MM/YYYY"
});
jQuery('#birthday3').datetimepicker({
  format: "DD/MM/YYYY"
});
```

```css
.overflow-x-scroll {
  overflow-x: auto !important;
}
.overflow-x-visible {
  overflow-x: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="col-form-label" for="comp">Table
  </label>
  <div style="width: 600px; height:600px;
    background-color: #cccccc;">
    <div class="overflow-x-scroll">
      <table width="1000px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="head">
          <td>Field Text</td>
          <td>Field Text</td>
          <td>Field Text</td>
          <td>Field Date</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center">
            <input type="text" name="hi_name" class="form-control text-center" />
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <input type="text" name="hi_name" class="form-control text-center" />
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <input type="text" name="hi_name" class="form-control text-center" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <div style="position:relative">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Birthday" name="birthday" id="birthday1" class="form-control ">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="head">
          <td>Field Text</td>
          <td>Field Text</td>
          <td>Field Text</td>
          <td>Field Date</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center">
            <input type="text" name="hi_name" class="form-control text-center" />
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <input type="text" name="hi_name" class="form-control text-center" />
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <input type="text" name="hi_name" class="form-control text-center" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <div style="position:relative">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Birthday" name="birthday" id="birthday2" class="form-control ">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="overflow-x-visible">
      <table width="1000px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="head">
          <td>Field Text</td>
          <td>Field Text</td>
          <td>Field Text</td>
          <td>Field Date</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center">
            <input type="text" name="hi_name" class="form-control text-center" />
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <input type="text" name="hi_name" class="form-control text-center" />
          </td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <input type="text" name="hi_name" class="form-control text-center" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <div style="position:relative">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Birthday" name="birthday" id="birthday3" class="form-control ">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tunn58/hda1uxne/3/

Is there any way to display the `datetimepicker` outside the **horizontal scrollbar** and **without** the **vertical scrollbar** like when using `overflow-x: visible;`? Or is there any other way to handle a long table with datetime input field?

I'm trying to change the overflow-x to hidden when the `datetimepicker` is showing and change it back to scroll when the `datetimepicker` is hiding, but some input fields are at the end of the table so I can't do that.

Comment: Hi tunn, most of the time it isn't necessary to do a fiddle you can do the snippets right here on the site without leaving the page. I created a snippet for you, you can do changes by clicking *Edit* -> below the snipeet *edit above snippet*

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to do that before.